# How to simulate network drops for each individual Docker container at will?

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

I want to perform some stress-test for the applications that are run inside docker containers. Simple scenarios like turn on/off dropping all the packets for a specified IP address.

I've tried some tools, but none of them seem to satisfy me:

1. Disconnecting containers from the bridge network - sadly it drops all connections, not only to the specified ips.
2. Setting up iptables rules from inside a container - it requires a container to be launched in privileged mode, which is not a great practice (I'd like to have an approach that is suitable even for production environments).
3. Modifying the host's iptables also doesn't look like an option - I'd like to create network issues for a specific container, not for all the containers on the host.

What are some possible ways I should look into?
Are there any chaos engineering tools that are to-go options for such needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For docker container stuff, we normally use https://github.com/alexei-led/pumba which basically brings you all the features of `tc` into the docker world. In k8s we normally deploy it as a DaemonSet and then (via a regex) attack specific pods / containers / apps). If you give us a more specific question I am happy to answer specific details.

Comment: Looks promising, and the ability to work with k8s is what we need in the future! Thanks!

Comment: maiksensi Please I have a question. I'm trying to build an observability platform to be visualised on Grafana. I'm running all my docker containers which includes prometheus node exporter on AWS EC2 and I would like to stress this Prom Node exporter docker container

I have set up the Memory Utilisation for the Prometheus Node exporter and the defined threshold is 70% (If it exceeds 71% then it triggers an alert) so the purpose of the stress testing is to make the container exceed the defined threshold. Please do you have any idea how I can do this?